# Read encoding of an existing connection object

Tags: r, character-encoding

Is there any way to get (and set) the `encoding` of an existing connection? For example:

```
con <- file(tempfile(), encoding = "UTF-8")
summary(con)
```

The summary lists the mode and if it has been opened, but not the encoding that the connection uses.

Comment: To make it easier to find an answers, what would you like to know that property for? I mean you knew it at the time you opened the file, are you using that information later in a part of the code that no longer can remember that property? Does the code need to work for other types of `connection` "objects"?

Comment: I need this within a function where the user passes a connection object as an argument.

Comment: Maybe try and modify [`do_sumconnection`](https://github.com/wch/r-source/blob/trunk/src/main/connections.c#L4910)?

Comment: Might be easiest to write your own wrapper which returns an object with a custom `class` which includes a `$encoding` element.

Comment: I'm still having a hard time imagining why this would be useful inside the function. Would you do something differently based on the underlying encoding? All of the conversion should be done invisibly inside the connection object.

Comment: I'm implementing streaming to/from connections in jsonlite. Because json *must* be UTF8, the function should either force UTF8 or warn the user when the supplied connection is using the wrong encoding.

Comment: The code you wrote there will read the connection assuming a UTF-8 encoding. As far as checking whether or not a text file is UTF-8, my impression is that it's not possible to do that, in general.

Answer (score 0):

I'm really not sure I understand well what you need to do. But assuming that

- the connection relates to an existing file on disk
- you definitely need to read from the file
- you **might** want to write to the file

Then you could do something like this if you were to force the UTF-8 encoding:

```
# Hypothetical connection used by the user (file must exist on dist, hence 
# the "w" here
con <- file(tempfile(), open = "w", encoding = "UTF-8")

# recup the attributes of the existing connection
con.attr <- summary(con)

# build a list of parameters for a new connection that would replace
# the original one
newcon.attr <- list()
newcon.attr["description"] <- con.attr$description
newcon.attr["open"] <- paste0("r", ifelse(con.attr$'can write'=='yes', "+", ""))
newcon.attr["encoding"] <- "UTF-8"

# close the original connection, and create the new one
close(con)
newcon <- do.call(what = file, args = newcon.attr)

# Check its attributes
summary(newcon)
# $description
# [1] "C:\\Users\\...\\Temp\\Rtmpo9ykjo\\file54744993321b"
#
# $class
# [1] "file"
#
# $mode
# [1] "r+"
#
# $text
# [1] "text"
#
# $opened
# [1] "opened"
# 
# $`can read`
# [1] "yes"
# 
# $`can write`
# [1] "yes"
```

For checking whether previous content was encoded using UTF-8 or not is a whole other story, so this may or may not be useful in your case.